# django EmailMessage exceptions

Tags: django, email

I am using django's EmailMessage class to send emails with the following code

```
message = EmailMessage(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    try:
        message.send()
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False
```

I would like to know what exceptions are thrown under what circumstances, for example, what exception can i use to handle wrong email addresses, bad internet connection and so on.
I really need to be able to tell the user why an email couldn't be sent.

I am using django 1.5 and have looked through the documentation without success.
Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django use Python [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/smtplib.html#smtplib) module. Check out the exception types listed there.